# IF condition in MSQL not returning data

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I used to have this code to filter a big DB based on many conditions:

... ".$_REQUEST['apellido2']."%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci and
personas.address_location_city = '016' AND ...

The problem comes in the last 2 lines. I use personas.address_location_city = 016 to check if the student lives in a certain town. Now, the variable changed and towns are stored from now on in address_location_iso_city.

A big amount of students have their town stored in address_location_city and some of them have it stored in address_location_iso_city. In order to solve this issue, I need the mysql query to check for boths, so I need to add this IF Statement:

```
if address_location_iso_city is null then address_location_city else  address_location_iso_city end if
```

But if I add it to the query doesnt work:

```
... ".$_REQUEST['apellido2']."%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci 
        and   ( if personas.address_location_iso_city is null 
                then personas.address_location_city = '016' 
                else personas.address_location_iso_city = '016' 
                end if) 
        AND   ...
```

any idea of what I am doing wrong? is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [COALESCE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) in place of your `if` statement. Like this.

```
COALESCE (address_location_iso_city, address_location_city)
```

It returns the first non-NULL parameter from its parameter list.

So, in a WHERE clause you can say

```
COALESCE (address_location_iso_city, address_location_city) = '016'
```

Comment: But it does not validate during the sql query if the town is 016, right? I would have to do it manually after the query, right?

Comment: See my edit. You can use COALESCE in a WHERE clause, no problem.

Comment: Yes, it does work now with Coalesce(), thanks so much! Did not know about this function before. Thanks!